# how to get friends profile pictures from facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, url, bitmap, android-facebook

i am trying to get list of friends profile picture from facebook by passing url,but i am not getting the profile pictures i tried below code

To get profile picture i called img.setImageBitmap(pick());

```
public Bitmap pick() {
String imageURL;
URL img_value = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
Log.d(TAG, "Loading Picture");

try {
    img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+"100007027988491"+"/picture?type=small");

} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {

     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());

   img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");

  //  e.printStackTrace();
}

return bitmap;
  }
```

but i am not getting picture,
please help me to solve my problem

Comment: ("http://graph.facebook.com/"+"100007027988491"+"   /picture?type=small"); remove that extra space inbetween id and /picture?type=small

Comment: @HardikTrivedi thanks for ur reply,i tryed but i am not getting.it execute catch statement. loading picture failed

Comment: I just got my profile picture using the same code, make sure that particular friend has profile picture, I hvnt tried what facebook is returing when there is not profile pic

Comment: @HardikTrivedi "100007027988491" has profile picture.but my code is not working,my logcat shows loading picture failed error

Comment: INTERNET permission on manifest file ? Make sure you are not runningthis code on main thread. Show me the output of LogCat

Comment: [{"picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-prn2\/t1.0-1\/c13.12.155.155\/s50x50\/984019_520239681371235_1155110450_a.jpg"}},"id":"100001556245842","birthday":"08\/21\/1986","name":"Thamma Gopalareddy"},{"picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-frc1\/t1.0-1\/c23.7.84.84\/s50x50\/995433_495272663881905_679005321_s.jpg"}},"id":"100001975273159","birthday":"07\/14\/1988","name":"Purushotham Puri"}   Loading Picture   Loading Picture FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "http" with "https" you will  get the profile picture.
https://graph.facebook.com/"+"100007027988491"+"/picture?type=small